# How does ServiceStack recognise the newly added folder?

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-razor

In my app, I am dropping a new folder and a set of files into my directory whenever a new hosting client has been created using code:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("MyClient", ...);
file.CopyTo("MyClient", ...);
```

the folders are like this example:

`- www.MyDomain.com/MyClient`

`- www.MyDomain.com/MyClient/Default.cshtml`

`- www.MyDomain.com/MyClient/js/default.js`

`- www.MyDomain.com/MyClient/img/default.png`

...and so on

Now if you visit the `MyClient` path, you would expect it to load `Default.cshtml`, but instead you will get a 404 page not found. Until you restart the hosting, then if you visit the same path again you get the correct `Default.cshtml` page content.

If I understand it correctly, SS builds the mvc folder paths only at startup, then it will not automatically add new folders until you restart your hosting?

Is there a way to make SS be aware of the folder structure changes?

Comment: What kind of files are you dropping, static files? Otherwise you probably have to configure the correct route

Comment: @LukeHutton, please see modification. They are files from a template folder, I copy them using code and drop them into the corresponding "MyClient" folder automatically when that client is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack creates a static cache of **top-level** files and directories which is stored in the private static `HttpHandlerFactory.WebHostRootFileNames` (in lowercase).

One approach is to use Reflection to add your new top-level `myclient` folder to the private collection. An alternative approach is to upload files/folders under an existing top-level folder, e.g:

```
/clients/MyClient
```

Nested files/folders are not cached so can be added and accessed after the AppDomain has started.

Comment: Is there any reason behind why WebHostRootFileNames is a static readonly list<string>, but the nested files and folders are not? Can't the root level also be created dynamically? Curious to know.

Comment: @Tom The top-level files/folders are cached for fast lookups and to verify if the request is for a physical file/folder or a route for a Service.